# VB ArcGIS 9.3 - Move column to the left

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I'm trying to move text that is not aligned to the far left of the column due to programmer input.  I'm trying to figure out the VB coding for it, but nothing seems to happen in the Attributes table (shp file).

example:

PERMIT ID

1-ZUN

1-ZOR

```
   2-SUM

4-PBR

   2-SUN
```

1-ABC

and so on...

I can't seem to get the out of alignment text to move all the way over to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
"column name" = LTrim(column name)
```

This will accomplish what you want in the Field Calculator.